# Identifying an insect in Cambridge UK

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I have come across an insect in Cambridge UK that I could not identify.

I tried to find this in various catalogues of local insects without success. The insect was about 1-2cm in length and didn't move at all until it was disturbed. I found it around 11am. We are currently experiencing high temperature variations (8C-20C).

Could someone please help identify it and point me at any useful resources I can use in the future?

[image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a greater bee fly, *Bombylius major*, a nectar feeder and generalist floral pollinator which pollinates hundreds of species of flowers. It lays eggs near real bee nests and it's larvae feed from the bee larvae.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombylius_major

Comment: Thank you!! What a fascinating creature, can't belive I have never come across it before.